# Rails won't save to database after tiny model manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coding my first Rails app at the moment and can't resolve this annoying error.

**What I want to do:** The app is connected to a user's dropbox account. The user can specify a path in which the app then looks for audio files. These audio files shall then be downloaded, the metadata, path, etc saved to a Song model in the database, which belongs_to the corresponding user.

I implemented a method that indexes the dropbox folder and saves the filename and the direct link already a few weeks ago. Now I added a line that saves the entire dropbox path to the database as well and all of a sudden nothing is saved anymore.

This is what my song model looks like:

```
require "dropbox_helper"
require "open-uri"

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :artist, :expiration, :is_cached, :length, :dropbox_link, :local_path, :title, :dropbox_path

  validates_presence_of :title, :is_cached, :dropbox_link, :dropbox_path
  #validates :dropbox_path, :uniqueness => true

  def self.fetch_basic_songdata(user)
    logger.info "++++DEBUG: Song#fetch_basic_songdata started"
    dbh = DropboxHelper.new(user.dropbox_access_key, user.dropbox_access_secret, user.dropbox_folder)
    logger.info "++++DEBUG: DropboxHelper initialized"
    songs_metadata = dbh.generate_audio_index
    logger.info "++++DEBUG: Metadata generated"
    #logger.debug songs_metadata.inspect
    songs_metadata.each do |smd|
      logger.info "Preparing song #{smd['path']} for saving"
      songdata = dbh.song_data(smd)
      user.songs.create do |s|
        s.title = songdata['filename']
        s.dropbox_path = songdata['path']
        s.dropbox_link = songdata['link']
        s.is_cached = false
        logger.info "Song #{s[:title]} generated"
        logger.info "Song #{s[:title]} saved to the data base"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now when I call `Song.fetch_basic_songdata(User.find(1))` in the rails console, it prints the following:

```
irb(main):002:0> Song.fetch_basic_songdata(User.find(1))
  User Load (59.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Song#fetch_basic_songdata started
Preparing song /audiomixer/01 - Paradise.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 01 - Paradise.mp3 generated
Song 01 - Paradise.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/02 - Weirdo.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 02 - Weirdo.mp3 generated
Song 02 - Weirdo.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.2ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/03 - As It Is When It Was.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 03 - As It Is When It Was.mp3 generated
Song 03 - As It Is When It Was.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/04 - Broken Promise.mp3 for saving
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
Song 04 - Broken Promise.mp3 generated
Song 04 - Broken Promise.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/05 - Way Of Life.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 05 - Way Of Life.mp3 generated
Song 05 - Way Of Life.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/06 - Bizarre Love Triangle.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 06 - Bizarre Love Triangle.mp3 generated
Song 06 - Bizarre Love Triangle.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/07 - All Day Long.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 07 - All Day Long.mp3 generated
Song 07 - All Day Long.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/08 - Angel Dust.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 08 - Angel Dust.mp3 generated
Song 08 - Angel Dust.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/09 - Every Little Counts.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 09 - Every Little Counts.mp3 generated
Song 09 - Every Little Counts.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Preparing song /audiomixer/10 - State Of The Nation.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 10 - State Of The Nation.mp3 generated
Song 10 - State Of The Nation.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
=> [#<Dropbox::API::File bytes=3710598 client_mtime="Fri, 23 Jul 2010 00:09:30 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/01 - Paradise.mp3" rev="4b6ad8fc0010df0f" revision=1265293564 root="dropbox" size="3.5 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=3731496 client_mtime="Fri, 23 Jul 2010 00:09:30 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/02 - Weirdo.mp3" rev="4b6ad8fd0010df0f" revision=1265293565 root="dropbox" size="3.6 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=3620319 client_mtime="Sun, 10 Jan 2010 19:50:28 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/03 - As It Is When It Was.mp3" rev="4b6ad8fa0010df0f" revision=1265293562 root="dropbox" size="3.5 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=3645815 client_mtime="Sun, 10 Jan 2010 19:50:28 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/04 - Broken Promise.mp3" rev="4b6ad8fb0010df0f" revision=1265293563 root="dropbox" size="3.5 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=3954295 client_mtime="Sat, 20 Apr 2013 07:09:30 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/05 - Way Of Life.mp3" rev="4b6ad8fe0010df0f" revision=1265293566 root="dropbox" size="3.8 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=4199193 client_mtime="Sun, 10 Jan 2010 19:50:28 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/06 - Bizarre Love Triangle.mp3" rev="4b6ad8ff0010df0f" revision=1265293567 root="dropbox" size="4 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=5002092 client_mtime="Sun, 10 Jan 2010 19:50:28 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/07 - All Day Long.mp3" rev="4b6ad9010010df0f" revision=1265293569 root="dropbox" size="4.8 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=3595686 client_mtime="Sat, 20 Apr 2013 07:09:31 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/08 - Angel Dust.mp3" rev="4b6ad8f90010df0f" revision=1265293561 root="dropbox" size="3.4 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=4307888 client_mtime="Sat, 20 Apr 2013 07:09:32 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/09 - Every Little Counts.mp3" rev="4b6ad9000010df0f" revision=1265293568 root="dropbox" size="4.1 MB" thumb_exists=false>, #<Dropbox::API::File bytes=6313648 client_mtime="Sun, 10 Jan 2010 19:50:28 +0000" icon="page_white_sound" is_dir=false mime_type="audio/mpeg" modified="Mon, 22 Apr 2013 12:27:54 +0000" path="/audiomixer/10 - State Of The Nation.mp3" rev="4b6ad9020010df0f" revision=1265293570 root="dropbox" size="6 MB" thumb_exists=false>]
```

To check if anything is saved:

```
irb(main):003:0> Song.all
  Song Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs" 
=> []
```

I also noticed that the lines starting with `logger.info "++++DEBUG:[...]"` are not printed at all. Before I inserted them, the `logger.info` lines below weren't printed. I really don't get that behaviour, can anyone of you help?

PS: I hope the information provided is sufficient. As the app's behaviour is totally random to me, I have a hard time understanding what's essential to the problem.

**edit:** Thanks for the comments! As recommended, I tried using `create!`. This is what it told me:

```
irb(main):002:0> Song.fetch_basic_songdata(User.find(1))
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
++++DEBUG: Song#fetch_basic_songdata started
++++DEBUG: DropboxHelper initialized
++++DEBUG: Metadata generated
Preparing song /audiomixer/01 - Paradise.mp3 for saving
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Song 01 - Paradise.mp3 generated
Song 01 - Paradise.mp3 saved to the data base
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Is cached can't be blank
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `block in save!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `save!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:14:in `insert_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:436:in `block (2 levels) in create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:344:in `add_to_target'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:434:in `block in create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:149:in `block in transaction'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in `transaction'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:433:in `create_record'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:123:in `create!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `create!'
    from /home/sloth/audiomixer/app/models/song.rb:21:in `block in fetch_basic_songdata'
    from /home/sloth/audiomixer/app/models/song.rb:18:in `each'
    from /home/sloth/audiomixer/app/models/song.rb:18:in `fetch_basic_songdata'
    from (irb):2
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `
```

So if I interpreted this correctly, the problem is that the `is_cached` variable appears to be blank (empty? nil?). I assume this being due to an error happening before the `s.is_cached = false` assignment. Any ideas how to find it?

Besides, I just commented some of the `logger.info` lines and added new ones instead. After I restarted the server, I tried again and it printed the lines I commented but none of the new ones. Do I lack some very important information about Rails using old files? I've been doing the same things during the last weeks and never experienced any such weird experience.

Comment: Too much info I think. Someone could steal your idea :D

Comment: Perhaps checking the `create` return value for errors would be informative.

Comment: use create! to see what will happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `validates_presence_of` with boolean attributes because it checks that the attribute is present by calling the `blank?` method. However, `false.blank?` is true, so it will never let you save a record when the attribute is false.

You may also want to note that the rails console doesn't automatically pick changes you make to your code. You need to either call `reload!` or restart the console. When using `reload!`, be careful that you don't have instances of objects created before the call to reload! hanging around - they may be referring to the previous version of the class.

Comment: Wonderful, this was exactely what I needed to know :) Thanks a lot for the info!